# Progress towards the "Strunk and White" badge?

Tags: support, badges

I remember having a look at how close I am to the "Strunk and White" badge, a long time ago.

I have been inactive for a few months now, and can't find it anywhere now. Can somebody help me here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like with the new review system the progress bars got reworked. The criteria for "Strunk and White" is the same as "Copy Editor", so just look at the progress bar for "Copy Editor" and when you get to 80 you'll get "Strunk and White".

More details with obligatory freehand red circles are on this [SO Meta answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/111341/188816).